# Make bloc instances global across a Flutter app and access them by some identifier in a dependency injected fashion way

Tags: flutter, dart, dependency-injection, bloc, service-locator

I have multiple model objects delivered by some data source in my Flutter app, each is identified by its ID (an integer field).

Each model and its state can be represented in multiple widget.

I'm making a bloc object **for each model object** (for example a model with ID of 3 shown in **multiple widgets** and they should share the **same bloc instance**).

From some of these widgets, I can send an event to the bloc instance, and have a new state, and of course, this state should be represented in all of the widgets that are sharing the bloc instance.

The scenario in my mind should be as follows when fetching the data:
1- Each model object fetched from some data source and is delivered to the presentation should search for its corresponding bloc instance.
2- If the bloc instance is created, use this bloc instance (and update its state if necessary).
3- If the bloc instance is not created, create one and use it.

My main problem is, I can't seem to be able to create those bloc instances **globally**, and access them in a "dependency injected" way. The dependency is the bloc instance and identified by the model ID.

I normally use get_it to register singleton instances, but now I need "**Singleton instances uniquely identified by the model IDs**"

Also, since blocs opens streams, these should be closed by hand since I think we can't use BlocProvider widgets in my case. If there is a solution to that, that would be much appreciated too.

Comment: That sounds very complicated. Why not have one bloc instance for a set of models? Then adding/finding a model can be an event, changes in a specific model can be an event.

Comment: @nvoigt It is indeed, but I think that in your case, the state that is going to be managed is over an entire list, and any small changes on one model in the list will need to re-render the entire UI.